# Limit Centroid Movement in scikit k mean clustering

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a array which serves as initial centroid (3 variables A,B,C).

```
X = np.array([[0.5, 0.1, 0.4],
              [0.7, 0.7, 0.3],
              [0.2,0.5,0.9]], np.float64)
clus = KMeans(n_clusters=3,init=X,n_init = 1).fit(data)
centers = clus.cluster_centers_
print centers
```

However for subsequent iteration, I want to restrict the movement of centroid between a range. Example: [0.5,0.1,0.4] can only change between [0.4-0.6,0-0.2,0.3-0.5] and so on.

Comment: To partially answer my question:
I added ~10000 points which have max,min,min/min,max,min/....... value of 3 variables to the dataset. This does keep the centroid between the range, however I cannot say about the comparative accuracy or statistical validity of method.

Comment: Why don't you just modify the code and prevent there mean from moving outside the desired range?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Constrained K-means Clustering, named COP-Kmeans ([see paper here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr-2000-65.pdf)).

It is a different implementation of the algorithm, and it is not available on scikit-learn. There is a python implementation of it [on this GitHub repository](https://github.com/Behrouz-Babaki/COP-Kmeans). Once you cloned the repo, it is used in the following way (taken from the "usage" section) :

```
run_ckm.py [-h] [--ofile OFILE] [--n_rep N_REP] [--m_iter M_ITER] [--tol TOL] dfile cfile k
```

And the arguments are the following :

```
dfile            data file
cfile            constraint file
k                number of clusters
```

There are also some optional arguments related to the algorithm itself:

```
--n_rep N_REP    number of times to repeat the algorithm
--m_iter M_ITER  maximum number of iterations of the main loop
--tol TOL        tolerance for deciding on convergence
```

And ultimately, arguments that are more meta, but also usefull:

```
-h, --help       show this help message and exit
--ofile OFILE    file to store the output
```

Comment: maybe I am wrong, but this is for constraining the relation between observation and the not the centroid. As in, it can specify observation which must belong together or must not, but have no way to control movement of centroid.

Comment: It is true that constrains are applied on observations, but this will guide your algorithm. Constrained can also be negative. If points on each side of your boundary cannot be linked, your centroid will not be able to overcome this limitation, and will thus be controlled